# Nuxt i18n Calling useRoute within middleware may lead to misleading results

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-i18n

So I am getting this warning in nuxt3:
`Calling useRoute within middleware may lead to misleading results. Instead, use the (to, from) arguments passed to the middleware to access the new and old routes.`

This happens because I am calling `useLocalePath()` in my middleware.

This is one of the middleware where it happens:

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async(to, from) => {
    const localPath = useLocalePath()

    const isUserAuthenticated = await isAuthenticated()

    if (isUserAuthenticated) {
        if (to.fullPath === localPath('login') || to.fullPath === localPath('register')) {
            return navigateTo(localPath('/'))
        }
    } else {
        if (to.fullPath !== localPath('login') && to.fullPath !== localPath('register')) {
            return navigateTo(localPath('login'))
        }
    }

})
```

I have this in my nuxt.config.ts:

```
i18n: {
        lazy: true,
        langDir: "locales",
        strategy: "prefix_and_default",
        locales: [
            {
                code: 'nl-Nl',
                iso: 'nl-Nl',
                name: 'Dutch',
                file: 'nl-NL.json'
            },
            {
                code: 'en',
                iso: 'en',
                name: 'English',
                file: 'en.json'
            },
        ],
        detectBrowserLanguage: {
            useCookie: true,
            cookieCrossOrigin: true,
            alwaysRedirect: true,
            cookieKey: 'i18n_redirected',
            redirectOn: 'root'
        },
        defaultLocale: "nl-Nl",
        customRoutes: 'config',
        pages: {
            pricing: {
                en: '/pricing',
                'nl-Nl': '/prijzen',
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the version of i18n that i'm using:
`"@nuxtjs/i18n": "^8.0.0-beta.12",`

The thing is, the code is working perfectly fine, but I don't have any clue why it's giving me this warning.

Is it safe to ignore this warning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async(to, from) => {
    const nuxt = useNuxtApp()

    const isUserAuthenticated = await isAuthenticated()

    if (isUserAuthenticated) {
        if (to.fullPath === nuxt.$localePath('login') || to.fullPath === nuxt.$localePath('register')) {
            return navigateTo(nuxt.$localePath('/'))
        }
    } else {
        if (to.fullPath !== nuxt.$localePath('login') && to.fullPath !== nuxt.$localePath('register')) {
            return navigateTo(nuxt.$localePath('login'))
        }
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

`useLocalePath()` uses the `useRoute()` method under the hood that's why you are getting that warn. one solution could be to use `useI18n()` instead and accesing the App locale variable.

```js
const locale = useNuxtApp().$i18n.locale;

if (!to.fullPath.includes("login")) {
  return navigateTo(`${locale.value}/login`);
}
```

or just add a re-usable composable.

```
export default function useTranslateUrl(url: string): string {
  const locale = useNuxtApp().$i18n.locale;
  return `/${locale.value}${url.startsWith("/") ? url : `/${url}`}`;
}
```

**Note**: make sure your locales are never in an `iso` format like `en-US`, unless your whole i18n configuration is setup that way.